# GAP on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: computational-mathematics, gap, programming, computational-algebra

I wanted to learn GAP as it is certain that it will be helpful in the future for my research.

I wanted to try GAP in Jupyter notebook in GitHub. I have tried following the step i.e. launch binder and I have reached the example page. When I write [GAP trial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk8bf.png) it gives me an error. So it looks like I am missing some step. Can someone please help me with what I need to do.

I have very little knowledge on coding and new on GitHub. So I would deeply appreciate any insights and tips.

Comment: delete the gap> in each line

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is really on-topic here (as opposed to on SO, for example), since the heart of the issue is more programming than mathematics. In any case, the error message should also tell you that the problem lies with the "gap" bit of your code. I don't know where your examples are from, but it's likely that the `gap>` part of each line is just to show the command prompt of the GAP system run from a terminal. It's displayed by the system and not part of your command, so you shouldn't include it when using GAP in jupyter.

Comment: It looks like someone copied the code from the command-line tool and included the prompts.

Answer (score 3):

As everyone suggested in the comments, `gap>` is a GAP prompt, it should not be part of the input.

Note that using this [example of GAP Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/gap-system/try-gap-in-jupyter) you do not actually run GAP Jupyter notebook on GitHub - instead, it will be executed on the service called [Binder](https://mybinder.org/). GitHub only stores the content of repositories, so saying "try GAP in Jupyter notebook in GitHub" is imprecise.

This question is not really on-topic here, but the [GAP tag on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gap-system) gets low attention, so for technical questions on GAP, I suggest to use GAP support channels mentioned in the `gap` tag description [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/gap/info). For the GAP Jupyter notebooks, you can submit issues to the GitHub repository of the [JupyterKernel](https://github.com/gap-packages/JupyterKernel) package. I will likely see such questions in any of these places.

On the other hand, I could imagine this question evolving into a more on-topic discussion about sharing reproducible computational experiments in GAP in a form of Jupyter notebooks runnable on Binder - you may find a template repository and links to several examples using it [here](https://github.com/rse-standrewscs/gap-binder-template).

Glad to see an interest in GAP - I am also one of the authors of the [Carpentries-style lesson "Programming with GAP](https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/gap-lesson/). It is intended for beginners, and hopefully you may find it useful.

Finally, after trying GAP Jupyter notebooks online to see if this is something you may find useful, you may decide to proceed with downloading and installing GAP locally from https://www.gap-system.org/Releases/, and using it via its default command line interface (or, in addition, install Jupyter and run GAP Jupyter notebooks locally too - may be easier to keep your work in permanent place and not in a transient instance on Binder, where it will disappear after it's closed).